# A seemingly contradictory result about measurements of Bell state with different basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

Consider the Bell state:

$$|\Psi^-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|HV\rangle -|VH\rangle \right) $$

Where $|HV\rangle = |H\rangle_A \otimes |V\rangle_B$ with $|H\rangle=(1 \ \ 0)^\dagger$ and $|V\rangle=(0 \ \ 1)^\dagger$. I'll define the basis:

$$|\theta\rangle = \cos \theta |H\rangle + \sin \theta|V\rangle \ ; \ |\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}\rangle=-\sin\theta|H\rangle + \cos \theta |V\rangle $$

The Bell state can be written in the following manner (it can be proven directly through substitution):

$$|\Psi^-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |\theta\rangle\otimes|\theta+ \frac{\pi}{2}\rangle - |\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\rangle \otimes |\theta\rangle \right) $$

Which means that if Alice measures the state and gets $|\theta\rangle$, Bob gets $|\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}\rangle$. The probability of measuring either basis vector is $1/2$. Now, take this state and this basis:

$$|\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|HV\rangle +e^{-i\phi}|VH\rangle \right) $$

$$|+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 \ \ 1)^\dagger \ ; \ |-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 \ \ -1)^\dagger $$

It can be shown that the probability of measuring the state $|+\rangle \otimes |+\rangle$ is   $(1+\cos\phi)/4$.Now, notice that if $\phi=\pi$, the probability goes to $0$. Similarly, if $\phi=\pi$, then $|\phi\rangle = |\Psi^-\rangle$. But it's also obvious that $|\theta=\pi/4\rangle=|+\rangle$.

The apparent contradiction is that, on the one hand, the probability of measuring $|+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle$ should be $1/2$ because it is independent of the angle, if you write the Bell state in the $|\theta\rangle$ basis. On the other hand, the probability of measuring $|+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle$ should be $0$ because if $\phi=\pi$, then $(1+\cos\pi)/4=0$. Can you help me?

Comment: Your account seems to be very unclear about what observations are being made.  You say that if Alice observes one particular value, Bob observes some other particular value --- as if this were independent of what Bob measures, which of course can't be right.  So at the least this needs more clarity.

Comment: @WillO What I mean is that when Alice measures one value, the state collapses to the other value. So for example, the Bell state written in terms of $|H\rangle , |V\rangle$, if Alice measures $|H\rangle$, the state collapses to $|V\rangle.$

Comment: There is a mistake in your question. For $\phi = \pi, e^{-i\phi}=e^{-i\pi}=-1$, so for that value of $\phi$ the state $|\phi\rangle=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|HV\rangle+|VH\rangle)\neq |\Psi^{-}\rangle$.

Comment: @alanf Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. The state $|\phi\rangle$ is defined with a $+e^{-i\phi}$, not a $-e^{-i\phi}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the $|\theta\rangle,|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle$, the $|H\rangle,|V\rangle$ states can be written as
$$|H\rangle=\cos\theta|\theta\rangle-\sin\theta|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle\\
|V\rangle=\sin\theta|\theta\rangle+\cos\theta|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle.$$

So in terms of the $|\theta\rangle,|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle$ states, $|\phi\rangle$ can be written as
$$|\phi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1+e^{-i\phi})(|\theta\rangle|\theta\rangle-|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle)+(1+e^{-i\phi})(|\theta\rangle|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle-|\theta+\tfrac{\pi}{2}\rangle|\theta\rangle)].$$

In the specific case where $\phi=\pi,\theta=\tfrac{\pi}{4}$:
$$|\phi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[|+\rangle|-\rangle-|-\rangle|+\rangle].$$
So the probability of $|+\rangle|+\rangle$ is zero.

There is no contradiction in this example. You made an algebraic mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I was confusing $|+ +\rangle$ for the single $|+\rangle$ state and that was confusing me. Your answer is correct.